# The minimal polynomial can't have multiple roots (in my proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, proof-explanation, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I have a question about the roots of the minimal polynomial $f_\alpha$, I can't see why $f_\alpha$ is separable, i.e. all it's roots must be different on a splitting field $\mathbf K$. I know it's roots are $\sigma_i(\alpha),$ but What is the proof to know that all the $\sigma_i's$ are different?

Proposition: If $\mathbf K:\mathbf F<\infty,$ and is Galois, then it is normal and separable.

**Proof:**
(summary of t.gunn's proof  :)

Let $\alpha\in\mathbf K.$

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is

$$ f_\alpha(x) := \prod_{\beta \in G \cdot \alpha} (x - \beta). $$
Indeed:

First, note that $f_\alpha(\alpha) = 0$, which follows since $\alpha = \operatorname{id}(\alpha) \in G \cdot \alpha$.

- Second, note that $f_\alpha \in \mathbf{F}[x]$,
- Third note that $f_\alpha$ is minimal. Indeed if $f(\alpha) = 0$ then $f(\sigma(\alpha)) = \sigma(f(\alpha)) = \sigma(0) = 0$ for all $\sigma \in G$. Thus $\sigma(\alpha)$ is a root for all $\sigma \in G$. Thus $f_\alpha \mid f$.

Finally, we note that $f_\alpha$ splits over $\mathbf{K}$ and is separable, by construction.

Comment: What is the definition of Galois extension you are using?

Comment: @Ennar $\mathbf K:\mathbf F<\infty$ is Galois if $G(\mathbf K:\mathbf F)^+=\sigma(\mathbf F)$, where $\sigma$ is the monomorphism between the fields

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation, do you mean that the fixed field of automorphism group of $K$ over $F$ is $\sigma(F)$?

Comment: @Ennar is the fixed field characterization, yes

Comment: Huh, I didn't read properly what is written at first, sorry about that. Well, as the proof says, it is separable by construction. Note how the product is indexed: $\beta\in G\cdot \alpha$. $G\cdot\alpha$ is a set, let's say $G\cdot \alpha = \{ \alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_k\}$. Then the product becomes $\prod_{i=1}^k(x-\alpha_i)$. What might be confusing you is that $k$ can be smaller than $|G|$, but it doesn't matter at all. If $g\cdot \alpha = h\cdot\alpha$, that just means that there exists $i=1,\ldots,k$ such that $g\cdot\alpha = \alpha_i = h\cdot\alpha$, not that $\alpha_i$ is taken twice.

Comment: Take extreme case such as $\alpha\in F$. Then by definition, $G\cdot\alpha = \{\alpha\}$ and the product becomes just $x-\alpha$ which is indeed minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$.

Comment: @Ennar No, I just wanted to see clearly that $\sigma_1\neq\sigma_2$ and so on..

Comment: Come on... Did you listen when we said $K/F$ is Galois iff $F = K^G$ where $G= Gal(K/F)$ is a group of automorphisms of $K$ ?

Comment: @reuns  are you angry?... yes I already understand what you wrote

Comment: They are not in general, but that is not claimed in the proof. In the extreme case of $\alpha\in F$, $\sigma_i(\alpha) = \sigma_j(\alpha)$ for all $i,j$.

Comment: @Ennar but they **must** be different to then conclude  that $\alpha$ is separable on $\mathbf K$

Comment: Why don't you read again what I already wrote. They _do not_ have to be, you are just misinterpreting the product. Please reread.

Comment: $$\prod_{\beta\in G\cdot\alpha}(x-\beta)\neq \prod_{\sigma\in G}(x-\sigma(\alpha))$$

Comment: Yes I am because you deleted the questions where I already explained that. No you missed something otherwise you wouldn't ask this.

Comment: @Ennar why they don't have to be? I already reread

Comment: You know that $I = \{1\} = \{1,1,1\}$, right? If I wrote $\prod_{i\in I}(x-i)$ it would mean $x-1$, not $(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)$. I will once again say, if $\alpha\in F$, then $\sigma_1(\alpha)=\sigma_2(\alpha)=\ldots=\sigma_n(\alpha) = \alpha$, $G\cdot\alpha = \{\sigma_1(\alpha),\sigma_2(\alpha),\ldots,\sigma_n(\alpha)\} = \{\alpha\}$ and finally, $$\prod_{\beta\in G\cdot\alpha}(x-\beta) = x - \alpha \neq (x-\alpha)^n = \prod_{\sigma\in G} (x-\sigma(\alpha)).$$

Comment: @Ennar Oh, I see. No, I didn't know that $I=\{1\}=\{1,1,1\}$

Comment: @Ennar but $\alpha$ is in $\mathbf K$, not in $\mathbf F$

Comment: Are you joking? $F\subset K$.

Comment: @Ennar no, I'm not. Why should I joke with this serious topics.. Does $F\subset K$ always holds?

Comment: Then please define field extension.

Comment: @Ennar Let $F$ and $K$ be two fields. We say $K$ is a extension of $F$ if there exist a monomorphism (of rings) from $F$ to $K$

Comment: Alright, then identify $F$ with its image in $K$ under this monomorphism. If you so wish, write $F' = \sigma(F)$ and replace $F$ with $F'$ everywhere.

Comment: @Ennar so first $\alpha\in F,$ then after applying $\sigma$ it goes to $\sigma(F)$ which is always a subset of $K$? Therefore $\alpha\in K$

Comment: Yes. It is very common in whole mathematics to identify set with its image under monomorphism unless we specifically want to study how many different embeddings there are. For example, we write $\mathbb Q\subseteq \mathbb R$ which technically might not be true, depending on particular construction of reals. On the other hand, we might consider extension $F\hookrightarrow K$ and identify $F$ with its image, yet, we consider all different embeddings $\sigma: K\to F^a$ that fix $F$, where $F^a$ is algebraic closure of $F$ containing $K$. This is what Galois theory is about.

Comment: @Ennar oh I see

Comment: Well, that is when $\alpha\in F$, otherwise it has more linear factors. Nevertheless, the factors are all different. You are welcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63049/discussion-between-anne-t-and-ennar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you listen when we said in your previous questions that $K/F$ is Galois iff $F = K^G$ where $G= Gal(K/F)$ is a finite group of automorphisms of $K$ ?

For $\alpha \in K$, it means that the polynomial with distinct roots $f(x) = \prod_{\beta \in G (\alpha)} (x-\beta) \in K[x]$ has coefficients in the fixed field, ie. $f \in F[x]$, therefore it is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

$G( \alpha)= \{ \beta \in K, \exists \sigma \in G, \sigma(\alpha) = \beta\}$.

$K^G = \{ \alpha \in K, \forall \sigma \in G, \sigma(\alpha) = \alpha\}$.

$f(x) =\prod_{\beta \in G (\alpha)} (x-\beta)= \sum_{n=0}^d c_n x^n, \quad \sum_{n=0}^d \sigma(c_n) x^n = \prod_{\beta \in G (\alpha)} (x-\sigma(\beta))= f(x)$.

$f \in F[x] \land f(\alpha) = 0 \land \sigma \in Gal(K/F) \implies f(\sigma(\alpha)) =\sigma(f(\alpha)) = 0$.

---

- Show the main statement when $K = F(\alpha)$ and use induction. It is equivalent to $|Gal(K/F)| = [K:F]$.
- Because $x^p-1 \equiv (x-1)^p \bmod p$ it means $\zeta_p$ doesn't exist in $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $x^p-t^p$ is the non-separable minimal polynomial of $t$ over $\mathbb{F}_p(t^p)$ so that $\mathbb{F}_p(t)/\mathbb{F}_p(t^p)$ is a non-separable finite extension.
- If $E=F(\alpha)$ where the minimal polynomial $f$ of $\alpha$ is separable then its normal closure (the splitting field of $f$) is Galois.

Comment: why did you mention the bullets?

Comment: This polynomial $f(x) = \prod_{\beta \in G (\alpha)} (x-\beta) \in K[x]$ has different roots, why?. I already know that $f\in F[x], $ and that $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Why did you write that as 'conclusion'?

Comment: @Annet. Are you serious ? $G(\alpha)$ is a finite set, we pick $\beta$ only once.

Comment: then why the product $\prod$ notation?

Comment: Of course I'm serious 

Comment: are you there reuns ? I'm still waiting for the answer...

Comment: @Annet. What is your problem ? Do you read the answers to your questions ? $\prod_{n \in A} (1-n^{-2})$ means we pick  each element $n \in A$ only once.

Comment: why? I don't understand why?

Comment: @Annet. The absolute Galois group $G = Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ has infinitely many elements, but for each $\sigma \in G, \sigma(i) \in \{i,-i\}$ : this is $G(i)$ by definition. Thus the minimal polynomial of $i$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\prod_{\beta \in G(i)} (x-\beta) = (x+i)(x-i) = x^2+1$.

Comment: why did you gave me $-1?$

Comment: It turns out I didn't realize that $G(\alpha)$ was a set!! haha

Comment: @Annet. No. It turns out you don't work on the answers. Stop asking 10 questions per day, stop asking 10 times the same question, search by yourself.