# Prove the extension $\frac{\mathbb Z_7[x]}{\langle 1+x+x^3\rangle}:\mathbb Z_7$ is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, galois-theory, extension-field

Is this solution correct? It's actually just the structure of the solution.

Prove that the extension $\frac{\mathbb Z_7[x]}{\langle 1+x+x^3\rangle}:\mathbb Z_7$ is normal.

**Proof:**

Clearly the extension is Galois (I proved with a lot of details in my exam and within the proof of that, I mention that $\left[\dfrac{\mathbb Z_7[x]}{\langle 1+x+x^3\rangle}:\mathbb Z_7\right]=3).$
So I have a finite Galois extension.
Now, by Theorem*, $\dfrac{\mathbb Z_7[x]}{\langle 1+x+x^3\rangle}:\mathbb Z_7$ is normal. ∎

Theorem*: All $K/F$ finite, normal and separable is Galois.

## Notes:

My professor told me that this solved exercise made by me is **wrong**, because 'I applied the Theorem* in a **wrong** way'. However the Theorem* becomes an *if and only if* when the extension $K/F$ is finite (which is my case, 3).

Definition: An extension $K/F$ is Galois if $G(K/F)^+=\sigma(F),$ where $\sigma:F\to K$ is a monomorphism.  (the fixed field characterization)

Definition: An extension $K/F$ is normal if every irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ with a root on $K$, splits on $K$.

The Theorem* was proved in class, however this side $\gets$ of the Theorem* was not proven, but in advisories my professor told me about it: Galois=normal+separable if $K/F$ is finite.

Did I miss something this time? :)

Comment: I delete the other one because someone:) told me that a lot things were missing, so you guys downvoted my question :(

Comment: Usually a Galois extension is defined as "an algebraic extension which is normal and seperable;" thus saying "clearly the extension is Galois" and then concluding that the extension is normal seems suspect

Comment: Do you read the answers to your questions ?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378438/finite-galois-extensions/2378472#2378472 The answer is the Frobenius automorphism $a \mapsto a^7$

Comment: @reuns :D always bothering...

Comment: @ThomasGrubb did you see my definition of Galois extension?

Comment: @ThomasGrubb Nop, it doesn't seems suspect, is the extension Galois? of course. Is it finite? of course. Therefore it's normal

Comment: If $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible then the Frobenius automorphism $\varphi(\alpha) = \alpha^7$ gives the minimal polynomial of any element $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_7[x]/(x^3+x+1)$. What do you want more ?

Comment: Also as I don't understand your definition of a Galois extension and I don't see the definition of a normal extension, I presume you have a problem about this point.

Comment: I edited my question @reuns

Comment: what is the problem with the definition about Galois extension $???????$ @reuns

Comment: Ok so what do you want more ? This is the answer : a Galois extension $K/F$ lets us find the minimal polynomials of elements of $K$, thus it is normal.

Comment: The problem is that you don't define your notation clearly, as if you didn't understand what the symbol meant.

Comment: $??????$ what symbol @reuns

Comment: this one + ? @reuns

Comment: Anne, have you got yourself in another dilemma? I'll have to read it tomorrow, since it's really late at my place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement of Theorem* is imprecise and grammatically incorrect.  From context, it appears to me that the precise statement is:

> Let $K/F$ be a field extension.  Then if $K/F$ is finite, normal, and separable, then it is Galois.

Assuming this is the statement of Theorem*, then is incorrect to say "by Theorem*" in your proof, because you are not using Theorem*.  Instead, you are using the converse of Theorem* (assuming the extension is finite), which is a *different* theorem.  It is fine to use the converse, but you need to accurately say which theorem you are using to have a correct proof.

Alternatively, perhaps the statement of Theorem* is:

> Let $K/F$ be a finite field extension.  Then $K/F$ is normal and separable if and only if it is Galois.

In that case, your proof is correct, since both directions are included in the statement of Theorem*.

Comment: Would have been correct if I had said 'By the converse of the Theorem*, the result follows.' ?

Comment: Yeah, that would have been correct (assuming the converse is a known result you're allowed to use).