# Cyclotomic Extension over Finite Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Let $p \neq 5$ an odd prime and let $\omega$ a $5$th root of $1$ in some extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Consider $\alpha = \omega+\omega^{-1}$ and prove:
>
> a) $(2\alpha+1)^2=5$
>
> b)$5$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p \Longleftrightarrow \alpha^p=\alpha \Longleftrightarrow p \equiv \pm 1 \ mod \ 5.$

For (a) since $\omega$ is a $5$th square we know that $1+\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\omega^4=0$ and then $$(2\alpha+1)^2 = 4\alpha^2+4\alpha+1 = 4(\omega^2+\omega^3+2)+4(\omega+\omega^4)+1 = 9-1=5.$$

However, for part (b) following the hints from @reuns I could almost finish it, but there is still a detail I have to work on.

Since $(2\alpha+1)^5=5$ we have $\alpha = \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$ then if $\sqrt{5}\in \mathbb{F}_p$ then $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and then $\alpha$ is a root of $x^p-x$, that is, $\alpha^p=\alpha$. Conversely if $\alpha$ is a root of $x^p-x$ and we know that this is the product of all factor $(x-\beta)$ with $\beta \in \mathbb{F}_p$ then $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and since $2\alpha+1=\pm\sqrt{5}$, then $5$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

For the other part if $p \equiv 1 \ mod \ 5$ than $\mathbb{F}_p(\omega)=\mathbb{F}_p$ and then since $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_p(\omega)$ we have $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and then $\alpha^p=\alpha$. If $p\equiv -1 \ mod \ 5$ then $p^2 \equiv 1 \ mod \ 5$ and then $\mathbb{F}_p(\omega)=\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. Now since $\alpha$ is a root of the quadratic polynomial $p(x)=x^2+x-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ then $m_{\alpha,\mathbb{F}_p}(x)|p(x)$ and then $deg(m_{\alpha,\mathbb{F}_p})=1$ or $2$. If this is one we are done since it will implie that $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_p$, but if this is $2$ then $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)=\mathbb{F}_{\omega}=\mathbb{F}_{p^2}.$

Any hint about how to conclude?

Note: I have a qualifying exam about this things in somedays, so I would like to have some hints about how to give one or two more steps and then I would like to try to solve by myself as much as I can!

Can somebody give me a hint to move?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, since $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ is cyclic, $\mathbb{F}_p(\zeta_5) = \mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ where $k$ is the order of $p \bmod 5$.

Comment: And what your exercice is proving is the quadratic reciprocity $(\frac{5}{p}) = (\frac{p}{5})$, which [follows from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity#Proof_using_Quadratic_Gauss_Sums) $\sum_{n=0}^4 \zeta_5^{n^2} = \sqrt{5}$

Comment: Okay, thank you! Then If I suppose $p\equiv 1 \ mod \ 5$ then $\alpha \in F_p$ and then $\alpha^p = \alpha$. But for $p \equiv -1 \ mod 5$ the order of $p$ is $2$ then $\alpha \in F_{p^2}$ and then $\alpha^{p^2}=1$, right?

Comment: Oh, yeah! I mean $\alpha^{p^2-1}=1$ and, therefore, $\alpha^{p^2}=\alpha$

Comment: Yes, this is general if $\alpha$ is the root of a polynomial of degree $2$, that $\alpha^p = \alpha$ or $\alpha^{p^2} = \alpha$. If it is the root of a polynomial of degree $n$ then $\alpha^{p^m} = \alpha$ for some minimal $1\le m \le n$ and $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha) = \mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378438/finite-galois-extensions/2378472#2378472))

Comment: Okay, now I need to find a way to conclude that this implies $\alpha^p=\alpha$ anyway

Comment: Hmm.. $(2\alpha+1)^2 = 5$ means $\alpha = \frac{\pm\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ and $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha) = ...$

Comment: Hmm, algebra scares me haha. But okay, let`s see, if $F_p(\alpha)=F_{p^2}$ means that the degree $[F_p(\alpha):F_p]=2$ then the set ${1,\alpha}$ is a basis for $F_p(\alpha)$, then since $\alpha^{p} \in F_p(\alpha)$ we have $\alpha^p = a+b\alpha$ with $a,b \in F_p$... Damn!

Comment: Thank you for you help, but I am still stuck! :(

Comment: I dont know if I can use $\alpha = \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$ because $p$ can be $2$, right?

Comment: With a) it makes it clear $F_p(\alpha)$ is $F_p$ or $F_{p^2}$. For b) If $\alpha^p = \alpha$ what does it mean ?

Comment: If $p=2$ then $1/2$ doesn't make sense, but this is a special case, forget it.

Comment: If $\alpha^p=\alpha$ we have $\alpha^{p-1}=1$ and, therefore, $p\equiv 1 \ mod \ 5$, right?

Comment: Yes but why ? $\alpha$ is not defined as a primitive root of unity, you don't know its order $\bmod p$ a priori. But what you can say is that $x^p-x = \prod_{c \in F_p} (x-c) $  (as polynomial with coefficients $ \bmod p$) and $x^{p^2}-x = ...$

Comment: Okay, so if $\alpha^p =\alpha$ means that $\alpha \in F_p$ since $x^p-x$ has this factorizations. So if alpha $\alpha \in F_p$ then $2\alpha+1 \in F_p$ and then $5$ is a square in $F_p$. This gives me the back direction of the first part in (b), right?

Comment: The fact that $(2\alpha+1)^2=5$ does not guarantee that 5 being a square in $F_p$ implies $\alpha \in F_p$, right? Because if implies that we have the foward direction of the first part too.

Comment: Yes from $\alpha \in F_p$ you get $\sqrt{5} \in F_p$, and conversely (if $p\ne 2$). So it leaves you with the $p \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ part, which is where the relation with $\omega=\zeta_5$ comes into play.

Comment: Ahh Gotcha! Now I have the first part both directions! Let me see the second.

Comment: Any hint about how to finish it? @reuns

Comment: To finish what ? I suggest you write everything you did in your question

Comment: Yes, @reuns, and thank you for that. There is one more case remaining but I will give up on that haha. Thank you!

Comment: @bttmbrcelo Let me resume the problem without being "scared of algebra". Following a), α is a root of the polynomial $X^2+X−1$ over $F_p$, so its degree over $F_p$ is 1 iff the discriminant, which is 5, is a square in $F_p$, i.e. the quadratic residue symbol ($\frac 5p$)=1, or equivalently, using the quadratic reciprocity law, iff ($\frac p5$)=1. But Euler's criterion states that ($\frac p5$)≡$p^2$ mod 5, so our condition is equivalent to p≡±1 mod 5, and we are done. See also math.stackexchange.com/a/2136375/300700 .