# Splitting over some extension of $\mathbb Z_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I want to write $x^3 + 2x + 1$ as a product of linear polynomials over some extension field of $\mathbb Z_3$.

I know that the roots will lie in a field that will be isomorphic to the field $\mathbb Z_3[x]/<x^3 + 2x + 1>$ but not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}_3$, do you mean the integers modulo $3$ or the $3$-adic integers?

Comment: The Frobenius automorphism $a \mapsto a^3$ gives as your polynomial is irreducible $X^3+2X+1 = (X-\alpha)(X-\alpha^3)(X-\alpha^{3^2})$ where $\alpha = x + (x^3+2x+1)$ is one of its roots in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+2x+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\omega$ the congruence class of $x$ in $\mathbf F_{27}=\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z[x]/(x^3+2x+1)$. This polynomial splits completely over $\mathbf F_9$:
$$x^3+2x+1=(x-\omega)(x-\omega-1)(x-\omega+1).$$

This means that $\omega\pm1$ are the other roots of the polynomial. Indeed
$$(\omega+1)^3+2(\omega+1)+1=\omega^3+1+2\omega+2+1=\omega^3+2\omega+1=0,$$
and similarly for $\omega-1$.

Comment: Edited the question, it was supposed to be Z and not Q.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense :)

Comment: Just one cavil: this is the cubic extension of $\Bbb F_3$, and thus it’s an $\Bbb F_{27}$.

Comment: @Lubin: Oh! yes, of course. I really was absebt-minded. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 1):

As your polynomial is irreducible, the Frobenius automorphism $a \mapsto a^3$ [gives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378438/finite-galois-extensions-of-the-form-frac-mathbb-z-px-langle-px-rangle/2378472#2378472)  $$T^3+2T+1 = (T-\alpha)(T-\alpha^3)(T-\alpha^{3^2})$$ where $\alpha = x + (x^3+2x+1)$ is one of its roots in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+2x+1)$.

Then you compute $\alpha^3 = x^3+(x^3+2x+1)= x+2 +(x^3+2x+1), \alpha^{3^2} = (x+2)^3 + (x^3+2x+1) = x^3+2^3 +(x^3+2x+1) = x+1+(x^3+2x+1) $ and hence

$\qquad\qquad T^3+2T+1 = (T-x)(T-x+1)(T-x+2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+2x+1)$.