# Trace of Finite Field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

Let $L=\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ be a finite field with $p^n$ elements, where $p$ is a prime number. We can regard this as a field extension of $K=\mathbb{F}_p$ (a finite field with $p$ elements) of degree $n$. If we consider the field trace $Tr_{L/K}(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in L$, by definition his is known to be the trace of the matrix $M_\alpha$ such that $M_\alpha: b \mapsto \alpha b$

As this is a Galois extension, we can alternatively define this as:

$$1.) \hspace{0.5in} Tr_{L/K}(\alpha)=\sum_{\sigma\in Gal(L/K)} \sigma(\alpha)$$

Then each $\sigma(\alpha)$ is simply a conjugate (or just another root) of the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$.

It is known that for all $\alpha \in L$, we have the relationship:

$$2.) \hspace{0.5in} \alpha^{\varphi(p^n)} = \alpha^{p^{n-1}(p-1)} = 1$$

Where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. I have also seen equation 1.) also written as :

$$3.) \hspace{0.5in} Tr_{L/K}(\alpha)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha^{p^i}$$

My question is then this: how does one use equation 2.) to construct a polynomial (which is then the irreducible monic polynomial for $\alpha$) for which equations 1.) and 3.) agree?

EDIT: I have seen some proofs where the authors start with the equation $X^{p^{n-1}}+...+X^p+X$, and then they show that this is an $K$-linear, surjective map from $L$ to $K$, as is required for the trace. Is this sufficient to prove that this is the trace?

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is  $\prod_{l=1}^d (x-\alpha^{q^l})$ [because $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the fixed field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378438/finite-galois-extensions-of-the-form-frac-mathbb-z-px-langle-px-rangle/2378472#2378472) of $\pi_q \in Aut(\mathbb{F}_{q^k}), \pi_q(a) = a^q$

Comment: Your number 2.) is incorrect: $\# L^* = q-1$, where $q=p^n$, and $L^*$ is a cyclic (multiplicative) group. Therefore $\alpha^{q-1}=1$ is the correct relationship ($\alpha$ arbitrary element of  $L^*$). Agree?

Comment: @reuns My question above is fully answered with Tsemo's answer in the question you hyperlinked. But in regards to his answer, why do we have that in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, that $X^{p^n}=X$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$? Then generalisation of Fermat's little theorem gives us that for all such $\alpha$, they satisfy $X^{p^{n-1}(p-1)} = 1 \implies  X^{p^{n-1}(p-1)+1} = X$

Comment: @user3343452 See the answers in the link. $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ is a group with $q-1$ elements so $X^q-X$ has already $q$ roots in $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: @user3343452 or see my comment: it answers your question in your comment (are you confusing ${\mathbb Z}/p^n$ with ${\mathbb F}_{p^n}$?).

Comment: @peterag Would we not have $Card(L^{\times}) = p^{n-1}(p-1)$? If we use the fact that $L\cong \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, then there $p$ elements which are not invertible, $\{0,p,p^2,...,p^{n-1}\}$, as we can multiply elements in this set together to get multiples of $p^n\equiv 0\pmod{p^n}$

Comment: Since $( \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ has $p^{n-1}(p-1)$ elements, $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field. As an example $\mathbb{F}_{5^2} = \mathbb{F}_{5}[x]/(x^2-2)$

Comment: @reuns Yes, its clicked, I have got it. Thank you